# Is there a work around for photoeditorSDK only working when dev tool are open on ie11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, console.log, photoeditorsdk

I am using the photoeditorSDK found here: http://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/html5/ version 4.12.0 and in the docs they claim to be internet explorer 11 compatible.  Currently, my code works in ie 11 but only when dev tools are open.  I have tested their demo and it also only works in ie 11 when dev tools are open so I the problem is a bug in the API.  I have contacted their support but they are ignoring me and I was hoping that someone could suggest a workaround to make javascript think devtools are open when they are not?

The error occurs when I call
    `var editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI({... stuff});` In my code.

Comment: I could reproduce your problem on my side. According to the [PhotoEditor SDK document](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/html5/v4/introduction/getting_started), I create a sample, in VS debug mode, it will show lot of "Invalid calling object" error in the PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI.min.js file. And, I also test the demo (in the document) in IE 11 browser, it also needs to open the dev tools. So, I think the issue is related to the PhotoEditor SDK, it is better to contact with them.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in a recent SDK update see link
https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-html5-build/releases